# Drupal 7: naming node with Theme Developer

Tags: drupal, module, themes, filenames, drupal-7

I'm working on a Drupal 7 website. I need a custom node for a page, and I used Theme Developer module to find the candidate name for the node which I attached screenshot below. But it doesn't take action when I name as node__28.tpl.php

What am I missing?! Thanks a lot! appreciate helps!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work with `node--##.tpl.php`.

And don't forget to clear cache.

Comment: oh I can't believe how silly I'm sometimes!! the double dash -- worked just perfectly!! thanks a lot!!!